# Spring mvc checkboxes

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jstl

I've got a list and everything works fine when using this approach, the problem is that this list is very long.
What I want to do is to put some html after half or something.

```
<form:checkboxes element="div" path="user.bags" items="${bags}" itemValue="id" temLabel="name" />
```

First of all, is there any way to manipulate this list? or do I have to loop through it?

When I loop through it it seems like it is doing something like this. I'm I even on the right track here?

```
<c:forEach items="${bags}" var="bag" varStatus="status">
<form:checkbox path="user.bags[${status.index}]" value="{bag.id}" name="?"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Any answer is good!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably pass two lists so you then specify the html. The checkboxes tag just creates the html ... to see exactly what it does just view your rendered page.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I think my explenation was a bit fuzzy. I want to split the list or put som html after half. To break up the list in 2 columns sort of.

Comment: split the list in yr controller... then you can just have two checkboxes tags referecnes the two lists

Answer (score 0):

Use varStatus to do modulo operation on it and then use any preferred number to check in C:if condition and then on every such occurrence use new column.